# Why does my itunes submission fail with "Invalid Signature" error?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, app-store-connect, application-loader, xcode-organizer

I am trying to submit an iOS app, but it fails showing "Invalid binary" in iTunes connect, and the submission feedback email shows:

> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a
>   distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development
>   certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are
>   correct at the target level (which override any values at the project
>   level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built
>   using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are
>   certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in
>   Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your
>   release target.

I am certain that I have used a distribution certificate.

I have ran the command `codesign -d -vvvv /path/to/app.app` and it showed `Authority=iPhone Distribution: Company Name Inc (ABC1234)` which is indeed a distribution certificate.

I used Xcode's application loader for the submission.

I also tried Xcode's Organizer - Archives to validate and submit the app. It passed validation (!) and then iTunes connect still decides it is an invalid binary with an invalid signature.

I should mention that I am using Xamarin, but I doubt that this is a Xamarin-related issue.

Comment: Hi user2320724. You should take a look at the project and validation from Xcode. I had an important issue with Xamarin: validation was successful with Xamarin but in fact it wasn't (there *was* and maybe *is* an error in Xamarin validation). So please go directly to Xcode and validate the project. You will probably find the real problem there.

Comment: I *did* validate using xcode, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Sorry then. I guess you have already erased all your profiles (you can do so from the iPhone Configuration Utility, not from Xcode 5 AFAIK). And double-check you use the App Store release certificate: Ad Hoc certificate is also a distribution certificate. Best of luck!

Comment: There could be a file being included in the IPA that Apple is rejecting. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30793765/503821